# Travis CI does not want Build project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, travis-ci

Can't understand why? Help please.
In log files travis trying read files from 2.1.0 version of Ruby, i think or i not correctly interpret situation)
I'm newbie in RoR)
This is just new project with travic.yml

Config:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.1.2
# gemfile:
# - Gemfile
script: "bundle exec rspec spec"
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring', group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-rails', '~> 0.3.2'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-nav'
  gem 'pry-remote', '~> 0.1.8'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker', '~> 1.2.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'webmock'
end
```

Log:

http://pastebin.com/V5aaMVna

Answer (score 0):

> 4.1.4/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:105:in `database_configuration': Cannot load`Rails.application.database_configuration`: (RuntimeError)
>   Could not load database configuration. No such file -

It's pretty self-evident that your build is failing because Rails cannot obtain a database connection.

Things to check:

- Have you specified the correct RAILS_ENV for your build scripts?
- Have you configured your tests to not require database connections, or if not, have you provided a database.yml in the *test* environment folder?
- Have you read online tutorials such as this one - http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/12/testing-series-rspec-setup.html ?